# Windows Phone 8 App - Tap on phone number in app, causes Unhandled exception

Tags: windows-phone-7, exception, windows-phone-8

Hey guys here is the exception that I am getting when I tap on a phone number in my app. I am trying to allow the user to tap on the phone number and dial it .

- $exception  {System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
    at Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.PhoneCallTask.NativeMethods.PhoneInitiateOutgoingPhoneCall_External(String pDialString, String pDisplayName)
    at Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.PhoneCallTask.PhoneDial(Object phoneCallTask)
    at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
    at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
    at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
    at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()}    System.Exception     {System.UnauthorizedAccessException}

Comment: Could you show us some code?

Answer (score 3):

Enable ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER in he Properties/WMAppManifest.xml in your solution

Answer (score 0):

try to use this Another thread..I mean use Dispatcher.Begin{}; and write code inside this block may run your code.

Comment: Please check your WMAppManifest file and check capability ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER.

Comment: U mean this:             var pct = new PhoneCallTask
            {
                DisplayName = "Name",
                PhoneNumber = "123456789"
            };

            pct.Show();